# Scala Spark, array with incremental new column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark is reading from cosmosDB, which contains records like:

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "answer": "2005-01-01 00:00",
            "answerDt": "2022-07-01CEST08:07",
...,
"id": {uuid}

}
```

and code that takes those answers and created DF where each row is new record from that array:

```
dataDF
    .select(
      col("id").as("recordId"),
      explode($"answers").as("qa")
    )
    .select(
      col("recordId"),
      $"qa.questionText",
      col("qa.question").as("q-id"),
      $"qa.answerText",
      $"qa.answerDt"
    )
    .withColumn("id", concat_ws("-", col("q-id"), col("recordId")))
    .drop(col("q-id"))
```

at the end I save it to other collection.
What I need is that I would like to add position number into those records.
So each answer row would have also some int number, which will be unique per recordId.
ie: from 1 to 20.

```
                  lp||           recordId|        questionText|          answerText|           answerDt|                 id|
--------------------++-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
1                   |951a508c-d970-4d2...|Please give me th...|              197...|2022-06-28CEST16:52|123abcde_VB_GEN_Q...|
2                   |951a508c-d970-4d2...|What X should I N...|              female|2022-06-28CEST16:52|123abcde_VB_GEN_Q...|
3                   |951a508c-d970-4d2...|Please Share me t...|               72 kg|2022-06-28CEST16:53|123abcde_VB_GEN_Q...|
1                   |12345678-0987-4d2...|Give me the smth ...|               10 kg|2022-06-28CEST16:53|123abcde_VB_GEN_Q...|
```

Is it possible ? thanks

Comment: try row_number()

Comment: @mvasyliv hmm thanks, but how to make row_number per  recordId ?

Comment: what col use to orderBy?

Comment: The row_number() is a window function in Spark SQL that assigns a row number (sequential integer number) to each row in the result DataFrame. This function is used with Window.partitionBy() which partitions the data into windows frames and orderBy() clause to sort the rows in each partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val w  = Window.partitionBy("recordId").orderBy("your col")
val resDF = sourceDF.withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(w))
```